# How to display buffered image

Tags: mysql, node.js, image, reactjs

I'm creating a "load picture" component in ReactJS. My component stores a loaded image in memory and sends it to a Node server that is using npm "file-loader".

The image reaches the server as a buffer `<Buffer 89 12 00 .... >`

I will try to save the buffer to a MySQL, but then need to display the image as a thumbnail in the browser if the DB insert was successful.

How do I display a buffered image in the broswer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I went with was to transform the buffer to base64 and display it with an `<img />` tag:

```
const buffer = someData // e.g., <Buffer 89 50 4e ... >
const b64 = new Buffer(buffer).toString('base64')
const mimeType = some_type // e.g., image/png
```

Then in my React component I render an image tag as such:

```
<img src={`data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}`} />
```

More here: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I think I might write a blog post off this. In the latest version of Node, `new Buffer()` is deprecated, `new Buffer.from()` is the replacement. Cheers.

Comment: @Sajicode glad I was able to find a solution for someone else! :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Sajicode! I was wondering why vscode kept crossing out my call for "new Buffer," and now I know!